# decompress multiple files from resource in c

Tags: c, windows, archive, compression

i have a visual c project, where i want to include an archive containing multiple files in a directory structure
i would like to programmatically extract it to somewhere on the disk, using a preferably small library (under small i mean just a few .c and .h files - size doesnt really matter), but i only seem to find libraries that decompress or compress data directly (i looked over lzo-lzop-minilzo, but i dont seem to find anything that says it can decmpress an entire directory tree even tho i used lzop already to compress the archive with the files)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

zlib and accompanying (in the `contrib`) minizip library support .zip format decompression.

You can pack the .zip file as a resource in your executable. To get the raw data from .exe use the `FindResource`, `SizeofResource`, `LoadResource`, `LockResource` APIs.

Then see minizip's samples to see how to decompress and read zlib's documentation to overload the I/O callbacks.

Disclaimer: I did this for [Linderdaum Engine's](http://www.linderdaum.com) virtual file system and there is now support for .zip, .tar, .rar (uncompressed) and .tar.gz formats. The code for VFS is in Src/Linderdaum/Core/VFS and it is under MIT license for non-commercial use. It's C++, but the I/O wrappers for zlib use C-style API and the code is pretty straightforward.

Comment: thanks for the info. i just looked over the source code, but i would like something more simple, like: extractallfiles(zipfile,targetfolder), because this particular exctraction is only a minor part and i dont want to implement another large framweork just to extract a single archive

Comment: MIT license is for non-commercial use only. Check: http://www.linderdaum.com/home/index.php?title=Licensing: